# Simplest Outlook add-in fails to load in Internet Explorer

Tags: office-js

We are developing an Outlook add-in using the JavaScript API. Our add-in works well inside native Outlook 2016, and when browsing to [outlook.office365.com](https://outlook.office365.com) using Chrome or other web browsers.
Trying to launch the add-in while browsing to the Outlook website using Internet Explorer fails to load it (We are getting the "Add-in Error" yellow notification at the top).
This does not happen on all of our computers. Currently, it happens consistently on one, and last week it happened on another computer, but have since stopped happening. Just to make it clear - on most computers, using IE, the add-in runs just fine.

I tried slimming down our add-in, trying to figure out what piece of our code is giving us the hard time. I have ended up with the most simple add-in possible, and it still won't launch on that single computer's IE. You can see this simple add-in [here](https://gist.github.com/ATGardner/8ab32841e12844b8335c12701af245d4).
This add-in links to the office.js and adds a simple text in a div in the initialize callback. It works just fine everywhere else, except that single computer.

My computer is running IE version 11.483.15063.0, Update Versions 11.0.44, if that makes any difference.

Has anyone else encountered this problem? What might cause it?

Answer (score 0):

You're loading Office too late which is triggering a timeout. Since it is a timing issue, you will see different results on different machines and browsers (also depending on network latency at any given time).

The problem here is you're not triggering Office.initialize until *after* the DOM has loaded. You need to initialize before anything else is triggered:

```
<script>
    // Initialize Office
    Office.initialize = function () {

        // Wait for DOM to get fully loaded
        window.onload = function () {

            // Execute commands against DOM
            var div = document.getElementById('after');
            div.innerText = 'after init';

        }

    };
</script>
```

I have a blog post on exactly this topic you might find helpful: [Super Simple Outlook Add-in](http://massivescale.com/super-simple-outlook-add-in/). It walks through building an add-in using nothing more than a static HTML page hosted on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it didn't work.
The add-in does not initialize office. It merely sets a callback for office to call, after it has initialized. If in that cb I then set another cb for onload - I'm already after the onload event, so it will not be called again, and the "after init" code will not run.
My code should work fine. Load office.js in the <head>, then in the onload look for window.Office until it's ready (just in case), and put in the initialize cb that sets the "after init"
I'm sure something is wrong with my code, but I still can't see what.
Thanks again for trying.

Comment: This isn't entirely correct. The `onload` and `initialize` events happen asynchronously and in parallel. In this case you're delaying the init until after the DOM is complete. Please see https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/loading-the-dom-and-runtime-environment#checking-the-load-status for an example of how this should be wired up.

Comment: Thanks for that link. I read through, and also checked the Phone Dialer sample (https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Mail-apps-for-Outlook-dc28341f), and it seems to have something that might work for me. I guess that is the case - on most computers onLoad happens before Office calls initialize, so everything works fine. But sometimes the initialize happens first, and I have to get it working well as well.
Thanks for directing me there.

Comment: A lot will depend on the page contents. `window.onload` won't be triggered until all of the page's resources are ready. Office.initialize is triggered by Office when Office is ready which may or may not happen before `onload`. If you had an add-in with loads of images for example it is likely Office will be ready before you page had fetched everything.

Comment: I have updated my gist. Now it first registers the initialize cb, then the onload cb, and sets different flags in them. Only when both flags are true, it does the 'afterInit' code. Again - it works fine mostly, but the problematic computer just doesn't run it. I see the index.html network request/response, but the code doesn't even run. I tried adding a "debugger" command in there, but it doesn't break in dev tools. It's as if the javascript is not running at all.

Comment: Is it possible JS was disabled on that browser? I would hope we've progressed past crazy things like that but it certainly still happens.